# How to create a listing like this:

Tags: listings

[image: Create a box like this]

What package do i need ? And what are the code lines i need?
Thank you!

Comment: I am not that familiar with LaTeX. I used the package "listings" and I used this code: \begin{lstlisting}[frame=single]
\end{lstlisting}, but the font size of it is too huge. Furthermore, it is displayed as code, what i do not want.

Comment: @Tester: Displaying code as code is the purpose of `listings` ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this perhaps?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcblisting}{listing only, listing options={language=tex},enhanced jigsaw,
    borderline={0mm}{1pt}{dashed,blue},sharp corners,,size=tight,fontupper={\tiny},boxrule=0pt,colback=white
  }
  \usepackage{color}
\end{tcblisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I get that error: ! LaTeX Error: File `shellesc.sty' not found.Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)Enter file name:! Emergency stop.<read >

Comment: Furthermore, how can i put a Label under the box like : Listing 01 ? Thank you very much!

Comment: Well, you have to update your TeX distribution then

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: @Tester: I don't know what your TeX distribution is. MikteX? TeXLive? Please consult their documentation. I am using TeXLive and that's pretty straight-forward

Comment: In addition, don't put extra requests to the answer. Post the question with your needs and issues and don't change or extend the question afterwards!

Comment: Yes you are right. I am sorry. It works now ! Thank you very much :)